# How to provide page range in process print request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, printing

I have a document which I am sending to print using below c# code

```
 p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
 {
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = FileToPrintPath//put the correct path here
            };
 p.Start();
```

Now, I have a condition where instead of printing whole document I want to print juts from page number `2` to `5`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the direct answer to your question but you can easily figure this out with using the code below. Show a dialog and choose page number, number of copies etc. and see how it appears in `printDialog1.PrinterSettings`. once you know the format, remove the dialog code and hardcode it into `Arguments`:

```
using (PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog())
{
    if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(**FILENAME**);
        info.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
        // Use the debugger a message dialog to see 
        // contents of printDialog1.PrinterSettings
    }
}
```

I wrote a quick test and here is what was stored in `PrinterSettings`:

> [PrinterSettings Microsoft XPS Document Writer Copies=1 Collate=False Duplex=Simplex FromPage=0 LandscapeAngle=270 MaximumCopies=1 OutputPort=PORTPROMPT: ToPage=0]

So you need to pass `FromPage` and `ToPage`:

```
info.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"" + "FromPage=2 ToPage=5";
```

In your code:

```
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = FileToPrintPath,//put the correct path here, 
    Arguments = "\"Printer Name Goes Here\" FromPage=2 ToPage=5";
};
```

Please not they are space separated arguments and if your printer name has spaces, you need to put the printer name within quotations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will it work in code behind of .aspx page?

Comment: If I understand correctly - I think this is assuming the application that is printing would need to support whatever arguments are passed. I'm not sure how this would fit with the print verb. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do the test in a windows application. It will be easier. All you need is to figure out what is `printDialog1.PrinterSettings`.

Comment: Ok..I tried the same in Windows App and now I am getting `FromPage` and `ToPage` in `PrinterSettings`. Now how can I add this in my code..please suggest..thanks

Comment: @wiz When we use a `PrintDialog`, it shows a dialog to the user and the dialog manipulates the `PrinterSettings`, thus as a test we can show the dialog and choose copies, page numbers (anything from the dialog) and then see what it sends to the printer. Then instead of using the dialog, we can just mimick that and hardcode it into the `Arguments` property.

Comment: thanks again.. I tried to add `Arguments = "FromPage=2 ToPage=4"` but unfortunately its printing entire document instead of just 3. I did not add printer name because its configured in my system and application uses the same..What's missing here?

Comment: @RAM Are you able to print pages 2 to 4 manually without using code? If you cannot, then you will not be able to do it with code either. It may be something to do with the printer.

Comment: I am able to print pages from 2 to 4 manually. Is there something wring with format `Arguments = "FromPage=2 ToPage=4"`?

Comment: @RAM No nothing is wrong. Are you able to print from that test windows application with the dialog only pages 2 to 4?

Comment: I am not able to check it from Winforms. Is there something else that needs to be done for Web?

Comment: @ram Perhaps the printer vendor has disabled programmatic access to that. Sorry I am not sure. You probably need to contact either the vendor or your IT department.